# inheritance n static variables

Tags: java, inheritance

Is static variable of superclass avilable to sub-class.
i.e i mean static variable of superclass can we access in sub-class without creating object  N without using ClassName.

Answer (score 3):

The same visibility constraints apply to static and non-static variables. So this is possible:

```
public class SuperClass {
    /*
     * public would also work, as would no modifier 
     * if both classes are in the same package
     */
    protected static String foo;
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public void modifyFoo() {
        foo = "hello";
    }

    public void modifySuperFoo() {
        /*
         * does the exact same thing as modifyFoo()
         */
        SuperClass.foo = "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: but then you could not access SuperClass.foo.

Comment: @vinay_rockin
Yes, you can. You can also write `SuperClass.foo = "hello";` instead of `foo = "hello";` and it will achieve the exact same result.

Comment: please see my edited answere and let me know if it is incorrect.

Comment: Lotzer, I am using c# and it does not work for me as I cannot access protected static variable by ClassName.variable. but I will take it as you say and read more on internet :).

Comment: @vinay_rockin 
The question is about Java, so my answer is also about Java. C# may behave differently in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In super class:

```
public static int staticVarName = 42;
```

In sub-class:

```
System.out.println("value: " + ClassName.staticVarName);
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of static variables/methods is that you can access them without creating an instance of the class.